# Need to get parent document's css to iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, font-face

In my parent document I have an editable iframe. In the parent document I have customised font-family implementation using `@font-face` inside the external css file.

This `@font-face` implementation is by default not carried to the iframe till I specifically add it there.

I read online that this is not possible till I actually add it specifically to the iframe as iframes provide css isolation from the parent document.

Is this correct or is there any way to inhert the css files from the parent to the child iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This may work; **may**. Inside iframe

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (parent) {
        var oHead = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var arrStyleSheets = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("style");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrStyleSheets.length; i++)
            oHead.appendChild(arrStyleSheets[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
}
```